# How to Check if a value is present in multidimentional object using javascript

Tags: javascript

My Question is i have an object in format:

```
        outerObject = new Object();

        outerObject["dynamicNameHere"] = new Object();
        outerObject["dynamicNameHere"]["position"] = 30;
        outerObject["dynamicNameHere"]["value"] = 50;
        outerObject["dynamicNameHere"]["done"] = false;

        outerObject["otherDynamicNameHere"] = new Object();
        outerObject["otherDynamicNameHere"]["position"] = 100;
        outerObject["otherDynamicNameHere"]["value"] = 500;
        outerObject["otherDynamicNameHere"]["done"] = true;
```

Now i want to check if 50 is present in this object. If it exist i don't want the same value to get added twice. The above is just example my objects are getting created dynamically. So how can i track the same.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to find if any outerObject["..."] contains the value 50 or if a specific has the value 50?  You need to clarify more precisely what you need to test for.

Comment: yes you are right am looking for a solution to find if any outerObject["..."] contains the value 50

Comment: Is it only the Value sub key that will be checked? If so this is not really a multi dimensional check since in JS all properties can be accessed as if they where an index key. So it is actually only a simple property check in an array. So you could probably change the title of the query ;) The more specific and explicit your question are, the faster and better the answers will be, and remember to mark an answer as accepted once you get one you like, that show that you play nice :D

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var itExists = false;
for (var key in outerObject) {

    if (outerObject[key].value == 50) {
        itExists = true;
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(outerObject["dynamicNameHere"]["value"])
 {
     if(parseInt(outerObject["dynamicNameHere"]["value"]) != 500)
     {
        outerObject["dynamicNameHere"]["value"] = 500;
     }
 }


 /*getting all the key and value in side object*/

 for(var key in outerObject)
 {
     for(var key1 in outerObject[key])
     {
         if(outerObject[key][key1] != 50)
         {
            outerObject[key][key1] = 500;
         }
     }

 }
```

Comment: Am looking for a solution to find if any outerObject["..."] contains the value 50

Comment: Hello john i edited the code please use for loop in side my code to find all the value in any java script object.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
        var globalretunval='';
        function searchObj( obj ,testval )
        {
            for( var key in obj ) 
            {
                if( typeof obj[key] === 'object' )
                {
                    searchObj( obj[key] , testval);
                }
                if( obj[key] === testval )
                {
                    //console.log( 'property=' + key + ' value=' + obj[key]);
                     globalretunval=obj[key];
                     break;
                }
            }
            return globalretunval;
        }

        var exist_tblno_in_obj=searchObj( outerObject, tblno1);
        alert(exist_tblno_in_obj);
```

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Don't use globals, use return values!